# operation is not supported - readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, blob, filereader, arraybuffer, amazon-lex

I am trying to convert a blob data to arraybuffer. So, i am using filereader,but i am getting error "operation is not supported".

```
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function      onSuccess(stream) {
      debugger;
      rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      rec.ondataavailable = function(e) {
          audioChunks.push(e.data);
      };
      rec.onstart = function(e) {
          audioChunks = [];
      }
      rec.onstop = function(e) {
          var blobData = new Blob(audioChunks, {
              type: 'audio/x-l16'
          });
          debugger;
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function() {
              audioCtx.decodeAudioData(reader.result, function(buffer) {
                  reSample(buffer, 16000, function(newBuffer) {
                      debugger;
                      var arrayBuffer =              convertFloat32ToInt16(newBuffer.getChannelData(0));
                  });
              });
          };
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blobData);
      }
  }).
  catch (e = > console.log(e));
```

Comment: are you sure it's `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blobData);` that's causing an error? perhaps it's the `audioCtx.decodeAudioData` that doesn't understand whatever the heck `'audio/x-l16'` is supposed to be

Comment: yup.thanks. i just found out that problem is with audioCtx.decodeAudioData.

Comment: reader.result is returning empty arraybuffer. What might be the issue?

Comment: @VinodhaSamiraja did you check that audioChunks actually contains data before it goes into blob? (it's not declared anywhere, neither is rec in the presented code at least).

Comment: kudo to @K3N's comment, do you define `audioChunks` to be an array ? Can you provide a real [MCVE]? For me, once this is fixed, [it works well](https://jsfiddle.net/a3uz6oL7/).